# Debugging a remote Linux application with Eclipse CDT on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, operating-system, gdb

I'm trying to debug a C++ application which is running on a Linux box. This application will not build on OS X. I've got the app running on the Linux box, and I can start gdbserver for remote debugging. But since the application doesn't build on OS X, is there a way to use Eclipse on OS X to still debug the app?

Answer (score 0):

Another way, assuming the remote Linux box is an SSH server and has gdb, is to run `gdb` on it thru `ssh`, e.g.

```
  ssh remotelinuxbox gdb -tui prog
```

Comment: Yes that works, but my question is more about how to get Eclipse debugging environment to work.